# What is IFA_UNSPEC payload in netlink response to RTM_GETADDR?

Tags: linux, networking

I wrote a program to query the Linux rtnetlink(7) interface using `RTM_GETADDR` for family `AF_INET`.
Parsing the response I realized that the biggest parts of the response seem to be `IFA_UNSPEC` type records of length 88 bytes (other parts are typically less than 8 bytes long).

Debug example output (for just one interface):

```text
  DB<3> r
index 1, family 2, prefixlen 8
flags permanent
host
# len 8, type 1
  address 127.0.0.1
# len 8, type 2
  local 127.0.0.1
# len 7, type 3
  label lo
# len 8, type 8
  flags permanent
# len 20, type 6
  cacheinfo: prefered forever, valid forever, cstamp 2.31, tstamp 2.31
# len 88, type 0
RT_Netlink::handle_response(lib/RT_Netlink.pm:361):
```

"len 88, type 0" is one `IFA_UNSPEC` chunk in the response.

So I'm wondering:
What are those unspecified chunks and why are they sent in the response?

This is what the manual page says:

```text
                        Attributes
rta_type        value type             description
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
IFA_UNSPEC      -                      unspecified.
IFA_ADDRESS     raw protocol address   interface address
IFA_LOCAL       raw protocol address   local address
IFA_LABEL       asciiz string          name of the interface
IFA_BROADCAST   raw protocol address   broadcast address.
IFA_ANYCAST     raw protocol address   anycast address
IFA_CACHEINFO   struct ifa_cacheinfo   Address information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem:

The problem is in the parser of the response (modeled after the C source in https://github.com/Yourens/rtnetlinkexample/blob/master/if_show.c as the original manual pages were *very* poor to understand how things work):

The response messages I got had these lengths: 76, 88, 88, 88

The first message the parser processed was 324 bytes, but the message length actually was just 52.
So somehow the parser parsed after the end of the current message, detecting the next messages as type `IFA_UNSPEC`.

Specifically the first message parsed had three times an 88 byte `IFA_UNSPEC`, while the second message had two times an 88 byte `IFA_UNSPEC`, the third had one time an 88 byte `IFA_UNSPEC`, and the last message eventually had no `IFA_UNSPEC`.

When I truncated the result of NLMSG_DATA() to IFA_PAYLOAD() before calling IFA_RTA(), those `IFA_UNSPEC` attributes magically went away.

I agree that everything sounds quite abstract, without presenting a lot of code that is absent in the question.

The basic Perl code to parse the response was (The original C structures are present as binary data, unpacked by corresponding `__U_`* routines. Probably that part had introduced the error as the example C code just advances a pointer while in Perl I used substrings):

```perl
    while (NLMSG_OK($response, length($response))) {
        my ($len, $h_type, $h_flags, $seq, $pid) = __U_NL_MSG_HDR($response);
        my $ifaddrmsg = NLMSG_DATA($response);
        my $ifaddrmsg_len = IFA_PAYLOAD($response);
        my $rt_attr = IFA_RTA($ifaddrmsg);
        my ($family, $prefixlen, $flags, $scope, $index) =
            __U_IF_ADDR_MSG($ifaddrmsg);

        #...
        while (RTA_OK($rt_attr, length($rt_attr))) {
            my ($rta_len, $rta_type) = U_RT_ATTR($rt_attr);
            my $payload = substr(RTA_DATA($rt_attr), 0,
                                 RTA_PAYLOAD($rt_attr));

            if ($rta_type == IFA_UNSPEC) {
                print "  unspec\n";
                #...
            } else {
                print "  unknown $rta_type/$rta_len ($flags)\n";
            }
            $rt_attr = RTA_NEXT($rt_attr, length($rt_attr));
        }
        $response = NLMSG_NEXT($response, length($response));
    }
```

The eventual fix was to replace the corresponding line with:

```perl
my $rt_attr = IFA_RTA(substr($ifaddrmsg, 0, $ifaddrmsg_len));
```

Finally here is a summary with some debug output showing the difference before and after the fix:

```text
### before fix
  DB<1> r
len 76, h_type 20, h_flags 2, seq 1, pid 7113
index 1, family 2, prefixlen 8
host
# len 8, type 1
# len 8, type 2
# len 7, type 3
# len 8, type 8
# len 20, type 6
# len 88, type 0
# len 88, type 0
# len 88, type 0
len 88, h_type 20, h_flags 2, seq 1, pid 7113
index 2, family 2, prefixlen 23
# len 8, type 1
# len 8, type 2
# len 8, type 4
# len 9, type 3
# len 8, type 8
# len 20, type 6
# len 88, type 0
# len 88, type 0
len 88, h_type 20, h_flags 2, seq 1, pid 7113
index 3, family 2, prefixlen 23
# len 8, type 1
# len 8, type 2
# len 8, type 4
# len 9, type 3
# len 8, type 8
# len 20, type 6
# len 88, type 0
len 88, h_type 20, h_flags 2, seq 1, pid 7113
index 4, family 2, prefixlen 23
# len 8, type 1
# len 8, type 2
# len 8, type 4
# len 9, type 3
# len 8, type 8
# len 20, type 6
  DB<1>

  DB<2> x $ifaddrmsg_len
0  52
  DB<3> x length ($ifaddrmsg)
0  324
  DB<4>

### After fix
  DB<1> r
len 76, h_type 20, h_flags 2, seq 1, pid 7534
index 1, family 2, prefixlen 8
# len 8, type 1
# len 8, type 2
# len 7, type 3
# len 8, type 8
len 88, h_type 20, h_flags 2, seq 1, pid 7534
index 2, family 2, prefixlen 23
# len 8, type 1
# len 8, type 2
# len 8, type 4
# len 9, type 3
# len 8, type 8
len 88, h_type 20, h_flags 2, seq 1, pid 7534
index 3, family 2, prefixlen 23
# len 8, type 1
# len 8, type 2
# len 8, type 4
# len 9, type 3
# len 8, type 8
len 88, h_type 20, h_flags 2, seq 1, pid 7534
index 4, family 2, prefixlen 23
# len 8, type 1
# len 8, type 2
# len 8, type 4
# len 9, type 3
# len 8, type 8
```

Unfortunately the fix seems to have swallowed the type 6 (cacheinfo) data; maybe there are more bugs.

### Update:

I found the solution (I think), changing:

```perl
my $rt_attr = IFA_RTA(substr($ifaddrmsg, 0, $ifaddrmsg_len));
```

to

```perl
my $rt_attr = substr(IFA_RTA($ifaddrmsg), 0, $ifaddrmsg_len);
```

as `IFA_PAYLOAD` seems to be the length of `IFA_RTA`, and not of `NLMSG_DATA`.
The whole netlink "packet" structure is quite a (poorly documented) mystery, or maybe even "misery".